# PostgreSQL: control reached end of function without RETURN

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a function which returns either X rows or 0 rows.

This is my code:

```
    ...
    IF var != '' THEN
        RETURN var;
    ELSE
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

If I do:

```
    ...
    IF var != '' THEN
        RETURN var;
    ELSE
        RETURN;
    END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  missing expression at or near ";"
LINE 19: RETURN;
```

Comment: does it return void?..

Comment: It returns text: RETURNS text AS $$

Comment: Please show us the complete code

Comment: I'm unable to, as StackOVerflow denies the update. Says there's more code than text.

Comment: did you declare output variables?.. I mean you cant return without anything if you did not

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tst_func(a bigint)
 RETURNS text AS
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A normal function like the one you defined (`RETURNS text`) will always return exactly one value.

So unless the function is defined as `RETURNS void`, you'll have to return a value, i.e. you cannot use `RETURN;` without an argument.

If you want to return a different number of rows (0 or a number greater than 1), you need a *set returning function*.

Such a function is declared as `RETURNS SETOF text` (or some other type), and from inside the function you use `RETURN NEXT val;` to add a row to the function output and `RETURN;` without argument to terminate execution.

Such a function can be used like a table in queries.